# creating an exe out of a small Python script

Tags: python

I created a small script using Python 2.7.

Using py2exe I have been trying to create an executable using [this tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial):

I am able to create the exe file called `sdf.exe`

I have all the necessary libraries in the directory with sdf.exe.

From the command line when I run sdf.exe, I get no errors and no messages; however the program does not do what it is intended to do which is to create a file called `output.csv`.

**When I run `sdf.py` it works without a problem; however, running `sdf.exe` does nothing and returns no errors.**

What am I missing? thank you so much!

Here's the full code:

```
import csv


thefile = []
output = []


def dowork():
    global thefile
    sourceFile='e.csv'
    thefile=ReadFile(sourceFile)
    CleanFile(sourceFile)    
    ProcessFile()
    AddHeader()
    WriteFile()

def ReadFile(filename):
    return list(csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[1:]

def CleanFile(sourceFile):
    global thefile
    iBalance=8
    iAging=7
    thefiletmp=[]
    for i, line in enumerate(thefile):
        if line[2]=='':
            del thefile[i]
        else:
            if thefile[i][iAging]=='':
                thefile[i][iAging]='0'
            thefiletmp.append(line[4:])
    thefile=thefiletmp


def ProcessFile():
    global thefile
    iCompany=1
    iNum=0
    iDate=2
    iAging=3
    iBalance=4
    COMPANIES=GetDistinctValues(1)
    mytemparray=[]
    mytempfile=[]
    TotalEachCustomer=0
    for company in COMPANIES:
        for line in thefile:
            if line[iCompany]==company:
                mytemparray.append(line[iCompany])
                mytemparray.append(line[iNum])
                mytemparray.append(line[iDate])
                iAgingCell=int(line[iAging])
                line[iBalance]=line[iBalance].replace(',','')
                if iAgingCell in range(0,31):
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                if iAgingCell  in range(31,61):
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                if iAgingCell  in range(61,91):
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                if iAgingCell >90:
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                TotalEachCustomer+=float(line[iBalance])
                mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                mytempfile.append(mytemparray)
                mytemparray=[]
        mytempfile.append(['','','','','','','',''])
        mytempfile.append([company+ " Total",'','','','','','',TotalEachCustomer])
        mytempfile.append(['','','','','','','',''])
        TotalEachCustomer=0
    thefile=mytempfile

def AddHeader():
    global thefile
    thefile[:0]=[['Account Name', 'Num','Date', '0-30', '31-60', '61-90', '91 Plus','Total']]

def WriteFile():
    global thefile
    out_file = open("output.csv", "wb")
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for line in thefile:
        writer.writerow(line)
    out_file.close()


def GetDistinctValues(theColumn):
    return sorted(list(set(line[theColumn] for line in thefile)))
```

Comment: Do you get any error output when you run `sdf.exe` from the command line?

Comment: @monkey nope i do not get any errors

Comment: Which directory is it putting the file into?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams as you can see the script instructs to create the output.csv file into the same dir as the program, but it is not creating it at all, i dont know whether it is creating it to another dir

Comment: Yes. I gathered that. What *is* the current directory?

Comment: C:\Python27\work\accounting\formatting quickbooks file

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the dir i specified above this msg

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you think if might be the long dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised it works from the non-compiled version at all. I can't see where `dowork()` is called.

I think you just need to add `dowork()` to the bottom of the scipt

Comment: @Артём Царионов: Add a _call_ to the function you defined, i.e. a `dowork()`, at the end of the script.

Comment: @martineau how come you italisized call and how did you italisize it?

Comment: @Артём Царионов: I did that to emphasize that you needed to invoke as well as `def`ine the function. To italicize a word or phrase in a comment just surround it with underscore characters like this `_italicized_`. You can find information on that and other formating possibilities by clicking on the "help" link next to the comment text box.